# How can I wait for an iframe to reload its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page that uses javascript / jquery to reload the contents of an iframe:

```
    $('#my-frame').attr("src","someotherpageinthesamedomain");
```

What I'd like to happen is to be able to manipulate the HTML of the iframe after it reloads. I tried this:

```
    $("#my-frame").load(dostuff());
```

But that does not wait for the reload -- I'm guessing because the iframe is already loaded with its original content.

Comment: you pass the result of `dostuff()`. You need to pass the function reference `dostuff` (no parenthesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the function, not call it:

```
$("#my-frame").load(dostuff);
//           no () here --^
```

Putting parenthesis after a function's name calls the function immediately and, in your case, will pass the **return value** to `.load()` (which is ok, if the return value is a function, but I guess it is not).

And yes, you might have to set the handler before you change the `src` attribute.

Comment: Hah. Thanks for catching my javascript n00b mistake.=)